# Python mirror image clockwise

Tags: python, jython

I have to:

Write the function `mirrorClockWise(source)` which mirrors each quarter of source in a clockwise direction. The top left hand quarter is mirrored onto the top right hand quarter. The top right hand quarter is mirrored onto the bottom right hand quarter.

Here is my code, only problem is the top right is different than what it should be because it is mirroring the top left that has already been mirrored, not the original top left.

Let me know if there is anyway I can fix this...

```
def topLeft(source):
    mirrorPoint = getWidth(source) / 2
    width = getWidth(source)
    for y in range(0,getHeight(source)/2):
      for x in range(0,mirrorPoint):
        leftPixel = getPixel(source,x,y)
        rightPixel = getPixel(source,width - x - 1,y)
        color = getColor(leftPixel)
        setColor(rightPixel,color)

def topRight(source):
    mirrorPoint = getHeight(source) / 2
    height = getHeight(source)
    for x in range(getWidth(source)/2,getWidth(source)):
        for y in range(0,mirrorPoint):
          topPixel = getPixel(source, x, y)
          bottomPixel = getPixel(source, x, height - y - 1)
          color = getColor(topPixel)
          setColor(bottomPixel,color)

def bottomRight(source):
    mirrorPoint = getWidth(source) / 2
    width = getWidth(source)
    for y in range(getHeight(source)/2,getHeight(source)):
      for x in range(mirrorPoint,width):
        leftPixel = getPixel(source,x,y)
        rightPixel = getPixel(source,width - x - 1,y)
        color = getColor(leftPixel)
        setColor(rightPixel,color)

def bottomLeft(source):
    mirrorPoint = getHeight(source) / 2
    height = getHeight(source)
    for x in range(0,getWidth(source)/2):
      for y in range(mirrorPoint,height):
        topPixel = getPixel(source, x, y)
        bottomPixel = getPixel(source, x, height - y - 1)
        color = getColor(topPixel)
        setColor(bottomPixel,color)

def mirrorClockWise(source):
    bottomLeft(source)
    bottomRight(source)
    topRight(source)
    topLeft(source)
```

Comment: `from PIL import Image; im = Image.open('path/to/image'); im2 = im.rotate(-90)`

Comment: @ffriend, that would rotate the image, not perform separate quadrant mirror operations right?

Answer (score 0):

Looping (over pixels) in Python is quite slow - if possible you should use an external library such as [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (Python Imaging Library) and the `transpose` method. I'm not sure if PIL is available from Jython though.

Regarding mirroring already mirrored data, you could:

1) It is common to pass a source and destination image into functions. Create a new image to store the result so that your source image is not corrupted while processing

```
dest = source.copy() # using PIL copy method
topLeft(source, dest)
...
```

2) Split the image into 4 parts, mirror them separately and reassemble the image (good use of external libraries will probably make this the fastest)

```
im1 = source.crop(box) # where box defines one of the corners
im1.load()
im1.transpose(FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
... do other corners
im.paste(im1, box)
... do other corners
```

3) Rewrite your algorithm so you can modify the data in place. For example instead of processing each corner separately, consider sets of pixels that map to each other:

First step

```
a......b      c......a
........  =>  ........
........      ........
c......d      d......b
```

Second step

```
.e....f.      .h....e.
........  =>  ........
........      ........
.h....g.      .g....f.
```

...

```
........      ........
i......j  =>  l......i
l......k      k......j
........      ........
```

Comment: can you show me what the code would look like for option number 3?

Comment: @user2877620 you should try implementing it yourself first, I'd be happy to provide feedback if you edit your post with the new code